# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() -> MySQL Connecting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

i have problem with my foreach... Can you please help me repair this problem ? Thanks guy :)

(It will be login)

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 33

```
        if(isset($_POST["UserName"]) AND isset($_POST["Password"])){
        $UserName = $_POST["UserName"];
        $Password = $_POST["Password"];
        $Password = hash("SHA256", $_POST["Password"]);


            $sql = "SELECT UserName FROM Login WHERE UserName=$UserName";
    foreach($db->query($sql) as $data) {
                if ( $_POST['UserName'] == $data["UserName"] && $_POST['Password'] == $data["Password"] ){
                    header("Location: index.php");
        }else{
        $cnt = 1;
      }
     }      
                if(!empty($cnt)){
        echo "Špatné jméno nebo heslo!";
      }


                if(!isset($UserName)){
                        $_SESSION["Time"] = 36000; 
            $_SESSION["LogedIn"] = 1;

    }      
                }   

        }
  }
  }
```

Comment: 1) you should look up prepared statements / parameterised queries. 2) `$UserName` needs quoted as it's a string 3) Look at the built in PHP [password API](http://php.net/password).

Comment: @JonStirling This is the correct answer.

Comment: 4) You don't request `Password` in your SQL, so that condition is never going to pass. 5) Try not to mix and match `&&` and `AND`. 6) Sort out your indentation.

Comment: Your SQL query is probably resulting in an error.  Probably because the string value has no quotes around it.  (Being wide open to SQL injection certainly doesn't help either, since technically you could be executing *any* code supplied by the user.)  Never *assume* that a SQL query will succeed.  Always check for errors before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` that mean `query()` fail and did not return an array.

There some errors, use prepared statements insted of put raw values at query, text/string type need quotes, in your query return the password not only the username if not a key named `password` never will defined an returned array.

correct code

```
$sql = "SELECT UserName, Password FROM Login WHERE UserName = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepared($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute(array($UserName)){
   print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
   exit;
}

$items = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($items as $data) {
```